# Automation Error while passing values in html page

Tags: vba

I trying to input values in a html page text box using VBA, it keep saying me automation error.

My code stuck at

```
ie.document.getElementsByID("VAR_VALUE_EXT_2").Value = "USD"
```

Not sure what is the error in the code, your help in this regard is greatly appreciated.

thank you

```
Sub test()

    Dim ie As Object
    Dim URL As String

    Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    ie.Visible = True
    URL = "https://eos-bw.ubs.net/sap/bw/BEx?cmd=ldoc&template_id=ZSAT_CO_EP_1_2_KK_TAB_DRT_PERF&sap-language=EN"

    ie.navigate URL

    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")

    ie.document.getElementsByID("VAR_VALUE_EXT_2").Value = "USD"    

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
ie.document.getElementsByID("VAR_VALUE_EXT_2").Value = "USD"
```

With:

```
ie.document.getElementByID("VAR_VALUE_EXT_2").Value = "USD"
```